# How many amps of Current is consumed in this circuit?

Tags: power-supply, current, circuit-analysis, raspberry-pi, current-measurement

I have this circuit: A battery connected to a DC/DC boost converter, that is connected to a Raspberry Pi computer.

[image: circuit.png]

[The detailed schematics of the boost converter can be seen here](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-powerboost.pdf)

The rest of it is obvious, we have 2 pieces of 1.5 V batteries, that are 3 Volts of Input Current. 
The output is 5.2 V, and since the cable is short, the voltage should not drop significantly.

## I have the following questions:

1. What is the maximum mA of current that the batteries can supply to the Raspberry?
   (My understanding is that it can supply 500mA at 1.8 V, but what happens when the voltage is lower, is there some formula that I can use to calculate how much voltage is needed for `X` mA of current?
2. How many mA are drawn by the input side (from battery to boost converter) in order to produce `X` mA of output current for the Raspberry?
3. What is the 2A internal switch, and what is it's function, I don't understand what that is?

Comment: What type of 1.5V batteries?

Comment: @AngeloQ Duracell AA alkaline batteries, 1.5V nominal voltage

Comment: think in terms of Watts and watt-hours. 2x1.5V alk.bat is not enough with wiki ref of 3.9Wh per cell

Comment: Why ask about 'amps'?   Isn't operating lifetime on a set of fresh batteries the more important consideration?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 ok, you can write your answer explaining the power difference in Watts too, that would be easier to understand. As AngeloQ explained the 10% efficiency loss in watts, is that a good way to look at it? How to tell what is the input watt vs the output watt, without measuring it. I would just need a basic theory on that.

Comment: @Whit3rd no I don't care about the operating time of the battery, I just want the theoretical answer to this problem. I can scale down the current usage if it depletes the battery too slowly, but I would just like to know the difference between input current and output current.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to work with the power dissipation for input and output to derive the input current.

The formula:

Pout * 1/efficiency = Pin

This becomes:

(Vout * Iout * (1/efficiency))/ Vin = Iin

For example, if the R'Pi draws 200 mA @ 5.2 V and the input voltage to the Powerboost 500 is 3 V.

(5.2 * .2 * 1.1)/3 = 380 mA

IF Vin were to fall to the minimum 1.8 V

(5.2 * .2 * 1.1 )/1.8 = 635 mA

Note: The Powerboost 500 is really configured to support a single Li-Ion cell, so the input low indicator comes on at about 3.2 V and less, so if you operate this from a 3 V supply the indicator will be always on.

I have powered a Raspberry Pi with this solution and it works well. I have tested it out to over 800 mA @ 5.2 V with no problems, though I use a single Li-Ion cell.

Answer (score 0):

1. You asked what happens if the voltage is lower than 1.8V, but you would be providing 3V.  1.8V appears to be the minimum voltage, so it probably won't run very well like that.  But as the voltage rises, you can draw more current from the output.  The reason is because the voltage is being stepped up, which means the current will drop.  Said another way, the input current will be higher than the output current, and it the difference will depend on the voltage difference.  I explain below roughly how that 500mA is calculated for a certain voltage.
2. They show 90% efficiency, although the actual amount will depend on the input voltage and current level.  But assuming 90%, you can approximate the input current by calculating the output power.  So if you draw 500mA @ 5.2V at the output, this is 2.6W.  Assuming 90% (although you probably want to assume lower efficiency to be safe), the input power would be 2.6W / 90% = ~2.9W.  Then you can determine the current given a certain input voltage.  E.g. For 3V in, the current would be 2.9/3 = ~1A.
3. The internal switch will be be turning on and off rapidly switching current from the input to the output while it boosts the voltage.  That current will be higher than the output current and also higher than the average input current, because it is flowing for short periods.  It could be twice the input current, depending on various factors of the switcher design.  The limit of that switch is 2A.  So in the 3V input example above with 1A input AVERAGE current, 2A may be a reasonable limit.  They appear to be less conservative in the spec because they say you could get 750mA from two alkalines and could go down to 1.8V while drawing up to 500mA at the output.  1.8V in with 500mA out means 1.6A average input current.  They feel the 2A switch current limit is sufficient for this.  You can probably safely assume it will, but it would be good to verify this for yourself.

If you are running a Raspberry Pi, you might need need more than 750mA, depending on your application.

Comment: Good answer, but I still don't understand 1 part. It says that it can supply 500mA at 1.8 Volt, but does that mean that it can supply less current at lower voltage. If I were to use 1 battery only, of 1.5 V, could it still work below 500mA? If I disable many components of the Pi, it only draws 200mA of current. So is it possible to provide 200mA from a 1.5 volt battery? I would like to know the formula with which you can calculate the voltage/ampere difference between the input and output.

Comment: It looks like they are suggesting max 1.6A average input current.  So the max output current for a given voltage approximately is Iout = Vin * Iin * eff / Vout = Vin * 1.6A * 90%/ 5.2V.  So for Vin=1.8V, Iout = 500mA.  But the device doesn't work below 1.8V.  It states "[this] module can run from 1.8V batteries or higher".

Comment: what would happen if I try it out with a 1.5 V battery, would it harm the device? Or it would just simply not run?

Comment: It shouldn't harm anything., but it would most likely not run at all.  There is an undervoltage lockout feature which will shut it off when the input voltage is below 1.6V.  You can see specs of the controller IC itself [here](http://www.ti.com/product/tps61090).